# Difference between BlocProvider(create..) and BlocProvider.value, if we separate out the lifecycle (creation and closure) of the bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, qq

Firstly, I am not sure if this is a bug. I am confused between BlocProvider.value and BlocProvider create.

In this particular scenario I am creating and closing a bloc in a stateful widgets init and close method. So as per my understanding that  suffices the condition of managing the lifecycle of the bloc

What is the expected behaviour if I call BlocProvider.create multiple times with the previously defined bloc instance inside that statefulwidget

In short what is the difference between

Scenario A:

```
BlocProvider(
// using the previously created bloc here
create: (context) =>_bloc,
child: widgetA,

BlocProvider(
// using the previously created bloc here
create: (context) =>_bloc,
child: widgetB
```

and
Scenario B:

```
BlocProvider(
create: (context) =>_bloc,
child: widgetA,


BlocProvider.value(
value: (context) =>BlocProvider.of(pageContext),
child: widgetB
```

I am not clear on this. Any help would be highly appreciated. If you notice I am managing the lifecycle of the bloc separately
So far I assumed both of these would lead to the same behaviour but I have been proved wronged recently. In my use case , using create twice is leading to "Bad state" even though the bloc.close() was never called. Replacing the secoond one with value constructor works just fine